# How do you make an Ackermann function "learn"?

Tags: java, recursion

How would I go about making the following Ackermann Function "learn" and memorize results of previous iterations so it doesn't recalculate the same things over and over? For example: It should learn that whenever it is given the input (2,2) then it should return 7 without running through the calculations again.

```
public static BigInteger ackermann(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    if (a.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return b.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return ackermann(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return ackermann(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), ackermann(a, b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

Comment: save them in an array

Comment: This is called _memoization_. It's typically implemented by a LUT or an associative data structure, keyed on the arguments and storing the corresponding value. For instance, you could grow a 2D array for this purpose, or invent a hash table. The function `ackermann` would first look up the data structure, return it if already available, and _only if_ the result isn't already computed would it attempt to compute it, save it in the data structure, and then return it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at memoization using Java 8: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization. This is by far the most elegant way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide short overview of the article, since this is an answer rather than comment.

Comment: This is an answer rather than an overview of something that has been succinctly explained in that article. You could be appreciative of the fact that I wrote more than just the word "memoization" which would have answered the question sufficiently :)

Comment: Sorry but this is link only answer. You are great contributer to this site so i am sure you are aware that links can become deprecated. Besides, OP asked about ackermans function and the single word to which the answer boils down does not show in fact how to make use of mnemoization on given function. Keep in mind that mnemoization can be used in other contexes, not only as optimization tecnique for the given problem.